# MongoDB error during save data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a question about MongoDB.
I want to save MongoDB data, but some(unspecified) error occured.
My server code is below.

```
router.post('/send/:to', (req, res) => {
    let chatFrom = req.session.loginInfo.username;
    let chatTo = req.params.to;

    if((typeof chatFrom !== 'string') || (chatFrom === '')) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'NOT LOGGED IN',
            code: 1
        });
    } else if((typeof req.body.contents !== 'string') || (req.body.contents === '')) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'NO MESSAGE TO SEND',
            code: 2
        });
    }

    Account.findOne({username: chatFrom}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else if(!data) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'INVALID SENDER NAME',
                code: 3
            });
        } else {
            if(data.chatList.indexOf(chatTo) === -1) {
                data.chatList.push(chatTo);
                data.save((err) => {
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////ERROR HERE
                    throw err;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    Account.findOne({username: chatTo}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else if(!data) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'INVALID PARTNER NAME',
                code: 3
            });
        } else {
            if(data.chatList.indexOf(chatFrom) === -1) {
                data.chatList.push(chatFrom);
                data.save((err) => {
                    throw err;
                });
            }        

            let newChat = new Chat({
                from: chatFrom,
                to: chatTo,
                contents: req.body.contents,
                isRead: false,
            });
            newChat.save((err) => {
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    return res.json({
                        success: true
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

An error occurs in '////////ERROR HERE' area.
and the error log is like below.

events.js:165
      throw err;
      ^

```
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (null)
    at Function.emit (events.js:163:17)
    at /home/jihwankim/Project/REACT/PurpleTalk/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3435:13
    at /home/jihwankim/Project/REACT/PurpleTalk/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:144:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

This is node.js application, and mongoose version is 4.7.7.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++
my model is like below

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Chat = new Schema({
    from: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    to: {
        type: String,
        trim: false
    },
    contents: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    isRead : {
        type: Boolean
    },
    sended: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('chat', Chat);
```

Comment: please share your model code and also specify which method is the source of exception in code above

Comment: Yeah, please share your schema. My guess here is: `findOne` is an async call. When node hits first `findOne`, node will put it on the execution stack and proceed forward only to get another `findOne`. If both the calls are trying to write in the same document, this error may occur. Can you try doing them synchronously by using promise?

Comment: Many things to figure out but please help to check if `data` is mongoose model or plain js object.

Comment: Like @AnkitGomkale opnion, it seems to be async issue... and I added my model code on the bottom of body content.